# Better usage of for loop in my Java Code

Tags: java

My code works the way i want it too, but it uses way to much lines.

Its about a food order terminal and the part i show you is about deleting 
JButtons from the shopping cart.

I dont wanna edit every single one JButton that is in the Arraylist. I thought a loop could help here but i have no idea how to do that.

Grettings

```
public class Bestellterminal { 

private int x = 0;
private double Preis = 0;
private double classicpreis  = 2.5;
private ArrayList<JButton> classiciconlist = new ArrayList<JButton>();

public void addComponentsToPane2(final Container pane) {

for(int i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {

    classiciconlist.get(i).addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (x == 0) {
                Preis = Preis - classicpreis;       
                Locale currentlocale = Locale.GERMANY;
                NumberFormat numberFormatter = 
                NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(currentlocale);
                String classicpreisx = numberFormatter.format(classicpreis);
                String preisx = numberFormatter.format(Preis);
                labelsumme.setText(String.valueOf("Summe: " + preisx));
                classiciconlist.get(1).setVisible(false);
            x++;
            }           

            else if (x == 1) {
                Preis = Preis - classicpreis;       
                Locale currentlocale = Locale.GERMANY;
                NumberFormat numberFormatter = 
                NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(currentlocale);
                String classicpreisx = numberFormatter.format(classicpreis);
                String preisx = numberFormatter.format(Preis);
                labelsumme.setText(String.valueOf("Summe: " + preisx));
                classiciconlist.get(2).setVisible(false);
                x++;
            }           
            else if (x == 2) {
                Preis = Preis - classicpreis;       
                Locale currentlocale = Locale.GERMANY;
                NumberFormat numberFormatter = 
                NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(currentlocale);
                String classicpreisx = numberFormatter.format(classicpreis);
                String preisx = numberFormatter.format(Preis);
                labelsumme.setText(String.valueOf("Summe: " + preisx));
                classiciconlist.get(3).setVisible(false);
                x++;
            }     


        }});


    }


}
}
```

Comment: Is there any difference between those three conditions?  Any line which exists identically in all three can simply be taken out of the conditions entirely.

Comment: That might be better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com though the first thing I'd check would be those if-elseif-blocks. They seem to be identical except the list index being used and that one could be calculated as `x + 1` (you'd need a range check for x then, e.g. 0 <= x < classiciconlist.size() ).

Comment: Too much repetition.  Needs to be DRY.  Only differences are the x value and the index in the list.

Comment: you should not use a fix value at `i <= 50`. should be the length of the list `classiciconlist`

Comment: Please explain the purpose of your code. What is `x` supposed to be? What result do you expect?

Comment: As far as I can tell the only difference between your statements is the index in the `.get()`, which seems to be dependent on `x`. From my point of view you could just do one block with `.get(x+1)` at the and and achieve the same.

Comment: but where is  ***labelsumme*** declared?? ???

Comment: The code is hard to understand without any comment

Comment: Btw, what is the meaning of `x`? Why do even the buttons whose text gets changed based on `x` get that actionlistener? How is `x` changed and what values are possible? To sum it up: your design seems to be flawed but fixing that would probably be way out of scope for SO, especially since we don't have any (or very little) clue as to how that code is meant to work.

Comment: Please read about the [DRY principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: I use x to go through the arraylist one by one. Everytime the one of the classicicon JButtons is clicked. 

The text (labelsumme) represents the amount people have to pay for their meals. 
I didnt put labelsumme in but i can edit it.

@duffymo exactly i dont wanna repeat so much. Thats my goal. To minimize the repetitions.

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza I will look into that, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are repeating your code - Make only 1 method and call it `myMethod(x);`

```
public void myMethod(int i) {
Preis = Preis - classicpreis;       
Locale currentlocale = Locale.GERMANY;

NumberFormat numberFormatter = 
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(currentlocale);
String classicpreisx = numberFormatter.format(classicpreis);
String preisx = numberFormatter.format(Preis);
labelsumme.setText(String.valueOf("Summe: " + preisx));
classiciconlist.get(i + 1).setVisible(false);
x++;
}
```

Comment: Ok i got it now (took a while to understand).
This works so good, you saved me alot of time and lines, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, the only difference between each branch of the if is the classiciconlist.get(x+1). If so, this is equivalent:

```
            if (x >= 0 && x <= 2) {
                Preis = Preis - classicpreis;
                Locale currentlocale = Locale.GERMANY;
                NumberFormat numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(currentlocale);
                String classicpreisx = numberFormatter1.format(classicpreis);
                String preisx = numberFormatter.format(Preis);
                labelsumme.setText(String.valueOf("Summe: " + preisx));
                classiciconlist.get(x+1).setVisible(false);
                x++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Many lines in the below code is duplicate. Try moving common code
>   out of if/else block and put only conditional code in respective if/else
>   block.

```
            if (x == 0) {
                Preis = Preis - classicpreis;
                Locale currentlocale = Locale.GERMANY;
                NumberFormat numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(currentlocale);
                String classicpreisx = numberFormatter.format(classicpreis);
                String preisx = numberFormatter.format(Preis);
                labelsumme.setText(String.valueOf("Summe: " + preisx));
                classiciconlist.get(1).setVisible(false);
                x++;
            }

            else if (x == 1) {
                Preis = Preis - classicpreis;
                Locale currentlocale = Locale.GERMANY;
                NumberFormat numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(currentlocale);
                String classicpreisx = numberFormatter.format(classicpreis);
                String preisx = numberFormatter.format(Preis);
                labelsumme.setText(String.valueOf("Summe: " + preisx));
                classiciconlist.get(2).setVisible(false);
                x++;
            } else if (x == 2) {
                Preis = Preis - classicpreis;
                Locale currentlocale = Locale.GERMANY;
                NumberFormat numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(currentlocale);
                String classicpreisx = numberFormatter.format(classicpreis);
                String preisx = numberFormatter.format(Preis);
                labelsumme.setText(String.valueOf("Summe: " + preisx));
                classiciconlist.get(3).setVisible(false);
                x++;
            }
```

This code should be good

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Preis = Preis - classicpreis;
            Locale currentlocale = Locale.GERMANY;
            NumberFormat numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(currentlocale);
            String classicpreisx = numberFormatter.format(classicpreis);
            String preisx = numberFormatter.format(Preis);
            labelsumme.setText(String.valueOf("Summe: " + preisx));
            classiciconlist.get(i+1).setVisible(false);
            x++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you have  a huge if-else-if_else that can be really shorted as:

```
if (x == 0) {
    classiciconlist.get(1).setVisible(false);
} else if (x == 1) {
    classiciconlist.get(2).setVisible(false);
} else if (x == 2) {
    classiciconlist.get(3).setVisible(false);
}
```

everything else is the same but with another names for the variables...

look:

```
//Preis is calcualted with the same formula no matter the value of x
Preis -= classicpreis;
//Locale uis allways German
Locale currentlocale1 = Locale.GERMANY;
//Number is the same(all for German Locale)
NumberFormat numberFormatter1 = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(currentlocale1);
//same  here
String classicpreisx1 = numberFormatter1.format(classicpreis);
//und here
String preisx1 = numberFormatter1.format(Preis);
//und  here
labelsumme.setText(String.valueOf("Summe: " + preisx1));
//x variable is getting incremented no matther what....
x++;
```

Comment: So far your tip worked for me. Still repetition i guess but it worked to shorten my code thanks :) Meanwhile i will try to figure out how the other answers might work out.

Comment: the missing trick is doing : ***classiciconlist.get(x+1).setVisible(false);*** but you need to be careful about the x value...